# Usage of words be ,been

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammar

I know the word **be** and **been**.but I don't know use of that

can you someone give some example for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Been" is just past participle of the verb to be.  I remind you that the verb to be is irregular, so perhaps this is causing a little confusion.

```
I am         - We are
You are      - You are
He/she/it is - They are
```

Compared to:

```
I have been        - We have been
You have been      - You have been
He/she/it has been - They have been
```

A simple example is:

```
I am tired. (first person singular of the verb to be present)

I have been tired.  (first person singular of the verb to have with past participle been)
```

Where you often see "be" used is in its infinitive form "to be", so:

```
I want to be an engineer.
```

"been" cannot be used in its infinitive form because it must be the past participle of another verb.  In the example below, been is accompanying "to have":

```
I would have wanted to have been an engineer.
```

I hope that clarifies it, though if you have any questions, just ask.